# Is the ideal of projective variety homogeneous when the projective variety is defined over a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, projective-space, noetherian, projective-varieties

We call the set $\mathbf{I}(V) = \{f \in K [X] | f(x)=0,\text{ for all } x \in V\}$ the homogeneous ideal of projective variety $V$. Indeed, if $f$ and $g$ both vanish on $V$, and $r$ is an arbitrary polynomial, then $f+g$ and $rf$ vanish on V. Furthermore, one of the homogeneous components of $f$ vanishes on $V$ and $\mathbf{I}(V)$ is finitely generated when K is Noetherian. Thus $\mathbf{I}(V)$ is a homogeneous ideal.

We know a field has only two ideals, the zero ideals and the unit ideal, so it is obvious that K is Noetherian if K is field. But what if K is a ring, is $\mathbf{I}(V)$ still a homogeneous ideal?

Comment: What is $X$ and what is $K[X]$?

Comment: K[X]:=K[X_0,X_1,...,X_n] is polynomial ring in n+1 variables. K[X] is noetherian if K is noetherian. So I(V) still a homogeneous ideal only if K is noetherian? But I don't know if we can extend the definitions about variety  to be over a ring directly.

Comment: If $f$ is not homegeneous and $x$ is a point in projective space, you cannot define the condition $f(x)=0$ correctly, because it is not preserved by multiplying all homogeneous coordinates of $x$ by the same number.

Comment: @danneks thanks